# Angularjs+jquery bootstrap-datepicker delegate not firing on first click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-delegate

I have tried adding the datepicker dynamically on button click and I have delegated the datepicker click which is not working on the first click its getting fired on the second click the code I have tried are the following

```
$scope.add = function()
    {
      var body =angular.element(window.document.body);
      body.append(`
        <div class="input-group date">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" 
                 placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"type="text">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      `);

    }

$(document).delegate("div.input-group.date", "click", function(){     
      $(this).datepicker({autoclose: true,orientation:"top"});       
});
```

I couldn't find out the reason, thanks in advance.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.5.0 (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) -->
    <script src="datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="test">
      <input ng-click="add()" value="Add datepicker" type="button" />
  </body>

</html>
```

[plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/muF0yNxUrJt6RrrmXZoy?p=preview)

steps to replicate bug:

1. Click `Add Datepicker` button
2. Date picker component will be added in DOM, then click in the datepicker

Observed

First click wont work, it will work from the subsequent clicks

Comment: Why are you doing the grave mistake of mixing angularJS and jquery. Why not use angular Date picker ?? You are missing `$digest` when using jquery

Comment: @ShashankVivek the jQuery code isn't modifying `$scope`, so lack of `$digest` or `$apply` is not the problem in this case.

Comment: You probably don't need to mix in jQuery, could you comment more on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This code uses an old version of bootstrap-datepicker (1.5) and an old version of jQuery (1.11). Instead of trying to fix the problem with jQuery delegate (which is deprecated), it would be wiser to use a bootstrap-datepicker that is integrated with the AngularJS framework. Consider the one by the AngularUI team: [ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!datepickerPopup)

Comment: @ShashankVivek, you are correct that I should not mix the jquery and angular, but Im working on the existing project, I don't have the authority to change the component, I need to add the set of component dynamically among that datepicker is the one.

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan : Ahhh... ok . lemme check it then

Comment: @ShashankVivek thanks for trying out the solution for me, however I got the solution and I have posted that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason and work around for the same. I am giving that solution since it may help to others in future

**Reason:**

First mistake is I have bind the datepicker event on element click so binding happened on the first click and it started working in subsequent clicks.

**Work around**

We have to bind the datepicker immediately after the element created I have solved this using the following code

```
$scope.add = function()
    {
      var body =angular.element(window.document.body);
      var element=angular.element('<div class="input-group date">\
                      <input class="form-control input-sm"\
                      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text">\
                      <span class="input-group-addon">\
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>\
                      </span>\
                  </div>');
      body.append(element);
      $(element).datepicker({autoclose: true,orientation:"top"});

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to make the date picker appear on click, then do it the AngularJS way:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.add = function() {
  $scope.showDatePicker = true;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<button ng-click="add()">Add Datepicker</button>

<div ng-show="showDatePicker" class="input-group date">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"type="text">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

When you click on the button with `add()` the `$scope.showDatePicker` is set to true and the datepicker is shown. You could also add a button to "hide" the date picker:

```
$scope.remove = function() {
  $scope.showDatePicker = false;
}
```

Or you could make a function that toggles it, where `add` and `remove` happen in the same function.

Comment: This answer shows a Material Design datepicker, but the question is about a Bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: Updated answer to use bootstrap

Comment: @EdgarQuintero thanks for the help, I want to add the component dynamically(n times) not static.

Comment: Ok, I do not see the (n times) part in your initial question. Also I do not see in your question where you mention you cannot NOT manipulate the DOM from the controller, if that's a requirement it should be posted.